# How to add an edit and delete function in my python app to edit or delete an entire excel row (not just the values but the row itself)?

Tags: python, excel, tkinter, openpyxl, delete-row

Here is my edited/stripped code that contains only the functions that needed solution:

```
def on_treeview_click(event):
    item = treeview.focus()
    values = treeview.item(item)['values']
    name_entry.delete(0, 'end')
    account_entry.delete(0, 'end')
    payment_entry.delete(0, 'end')
    if values:
        name_entry.insert(0, values[0])
        account_entry.insert(0, values[3])
        payment_entry.insert(0, values[2])

def update_data():
    name = name_entry.get()
    account = account_entry.get()
    payment = payment_entry.get()

    if name and account and payment:
        # Calculate the balance
        try:
            balance = float(account) - float(payment)
        except ValueError:
            balance = ""

        # Insert or update row in Excel sheet
        path = "accounts.xlsx"
        workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
        sheet = workbook.active
        row_values = [name, account, payment, balance]

        # Check if the name already exists in the sheet
        name_exists = False
        for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=2, values_only=True):
            if row[0] == name:
                row[1] = account
                row[2] = payment
                row[3] = balance
                name_exists = True
                break

        if not name_exists:
            sheet.append(row_values)

        workbook.save(path)

        # Insert row into treeview
        treeview.insert('', tk.END, values=row_values)

        # Clear the values
        name_entry.delete(0, "end")
        name_entry.insert(0, "Name")
        account_entry.delete(0, "end")
        account_entry.insert(0, "Account")
        payment_entry.delete(0, "end")
        payment_entry.insert(0, "Payment")

def delete_data():
    # Insert or update row in Excel sheet
    path = "accounts.xlsx"
    workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
    sheet = workbook.active

    # get the selected items from the treeview
    selection = treeview.selection()
    for item in selection:
        # extract the row number from the treeview item tag
        tags = treeview.item(treeview.focus(), 'tags')
        if tags:
            row = int(treeview.item(treeview.focus(), 'tags')[0])
            # delete the row from the sheet
            sheet.delete_rows(row)
            # delete the item from the treeview
            treeview.delete(item)

    # save the changes to the workbook
    workbook.save('accounts.xlsx')

button = ttk.Button(widgets_frame, text="Save Data", command=save_data)
button.grid(row=4, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="nsew")

button = ttk.Button(widgets_frame, text="Update Data", command=save_data)
button.grid(row=5, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="nsew")

button = ttk.Button(widgets_frame, text="Refresh Data", command=refresh_data)
button.grid(row=6, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="nsew")

button = ttk.Button(widgets_frame, text="Delete Data", command=delete_data)
button.grid(row=7, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="nsew")

cols = ("Student Name", "Account", "Payment", "New Balance")
treeview = ttk.Treeview(treeFrame, show="headings",
                        yscrollcommand=treeScroll.set, columns=cols, height=13)
treeview.column("Student Name", width=200)
treeview.column("Account", width=150)
treeview.column("Payment", width=150)
treeview.column("New Balance", width=150)
treeview.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
treeview.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", on_treeview_click)
treeScroll.config(command=treeview.yview)

load_data()

# Set the weight of the rows and columns to 1, so they expand to fill the available space
root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

root.mainloop()
```

I am not really a programmer I just scrapped codes from anywhere and trying to build an app. This one would be useful in our small school.

As you can see in my code, I already have a functions called update_data() and delete_data(), however, when i click the button "Delete Data" nothing happens and when I click the "Update Data" it creates a new data in a new row.

What I want to accomplish is that in my

```
onclick_treeview_click(event)
```

the treeview item being focused/selected/clicked; the entire row from which it is taken can be edited or deleted thru the update_data() and delete_data() functions.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).